# Alertview: alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton method can't detect subview textView

Tags: ios, uialertview

I create a custom alertview that subview a uitextview inside it, as shown in the screenshot.

[alertview with subviewed textview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqPeZ.png)

I want to disable the Submit button when the textview is empty, so I edited the alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton method:

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    if ( alertView.tag == 5000 ) {

    for(UIView *view in alertView.subviews) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
            UITextView *textField = (UITextView *)view;

            if ( textField.text.length == 0 ) {
                return NO ;
            }
            return YES ;

        }
    }
}

else {

    return YES ;
}

}
```

Initially, the Submit button is disable which is right, but after I edit (type something on the textview), the submit button is still disabled, it seems that the alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton only call once.

So, can someone teach me how to enable the submit button after I type in something on the subviewed textview? Thanks for the great help.

##########First edit

Below is the full code about the alertview,

```
- (void)addRemarkAlert {

alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Remarks\n\n\n\n\n\n"]
                      message:nil
                      delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Submit", nil ];

// textView to subview in the alertview
textView_onAlertView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 260, 100)];
textView_onAlertView.delegate = self ;
textView_onAlertView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
textView_onAlertView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
textView_onAlertView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
textView_onAlertView.clipsToBounds = YES ;
textView_onAlertView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo ;
textView_onAlertView.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences ;
textView_onAlertView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12];
[alert addSubview:textView_onAlertView];

alert.tag = 5000 ;
[alert show];

}

- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{

if ( alertView.tag == 5000 ) {

    for(UIView *view in alertView.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *aButton = (UIButton *)view;
            if([aButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Submit"])
            {
                if ( textView_onAlertView.text.length> 0 )
                {
                    ((UIButton *) view).enabled = YES;

                }
                else
                {

                    ((UIButton *) view).enabled = NO;

                }
            }
        }
    }


    return NO;
}

else {

    return YES ;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    NSLog(@"%d",tv.text.length);

    for(UIView *view in alertView.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *aButton = (UIButton *)view;
            if([aButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"done"])
            {
                if ( tv.text.length> 0 )
                {
                    ((UIButton *) view).enabled = YES;
                }
                else
                {
                    ((UIButton *) view).enabled = NO;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return NO;
}

//////////////////////////////////////Entire code for your question

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addRemarkAlert];
}

- (void)addRemarkAlert
{
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
             initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Remarks\n\n\n\n\n\n"]
             message:nil
             delegate:self
             cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
             otherButtonTitles:@"Submit", nil ];

    // textView to subview in the alertview
    textView_onAlertView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 260, 100)];
    textView_onAlertView.delegate = self ;
    textView_onAlertView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    textView_onAlertView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
    textView_onAlertView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    textView_onAlertView.clipsToBounds = YES ;
    textView_onAlertView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo ;
    textView_onAlertView.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences ;
    textView_onAlertView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12];
    [alert addSubview:textView_onAlertView];

    alert.tag = 5000 ;
    [alert show];
}

- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{

    if ( alertView.tag == 5000 ) {

        for(UIView *view in alertView.subviews)
        {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                UIButton *aButton = (UIButton *)view;
                if([aButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Submit"])
                {
                    if ( textView_onAlertView.text.length> 0 )
                    {
                        ((UIButton *) view).enabled = YES;

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        ((UIButton *) view).enabled = NO;

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES ;
    }
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [self alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:alert];
}
```

Comment: Thanks once again the reply, but this will only always enable the submit button, since the alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton always return true

Comment: Write your piece of code in alertviewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton... and it will work in accordance to your need.

Comment: Try the above Code I have cross checked it and it is working fine for me. @ManLungChan

Comment: Thanks for your great help to this question, although I still getting no work to enable the submit button. I give up and use other approach that pump another alertview after the user press the submit button while the textView is empty...

Comment: If you don't mind post your code here and i would make changes to it.

Comment: In ViewDidLoad I am calling addRemarkAlert.And in textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView delegate method i am calling the alertview delegate explicitly... check it.

Comment: Finally work with charm, I really really thanks for your patience to teach me and correct my mistake, thanks.